# Disable "Auto Restart after BSOD" from Command Line

Tags: command-line, bsod

I just did a major system upgrade (CPU, MB, RAM). The old HD doesn't like my new equipment (which resulted in a BSOD). I feel like I could fix the issue if I knew how to disable the auto-restart.

How do I disable the auto-restart after crash from the command line?

Comment: Well, I feel stupid answering my own question, but...

in Windows 7, if you hit f8 before POST, one of the options is "disable auto-restart after failure."

got the error code... may have a new question to post.

Comment: You can **answer your own question** using the button below in 8 hours or so, that would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already solved this, but just in case other people come here in the future, the problem is windows installs drivers specifically for what motherboard chip set you are using. If you change to a different motherboard 90% of the time you get the problem you ran in to.

Normally it is recommended to just do a clean install of windows when you change motherboards but I have seen that sometimes you can just get away with doing a "Repair" install and it will see the new motherboard chip set and install the correct new drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to answer my own question right away, but I had to wait the time limit...

In Windows 7, if you hit f8 before POST, one fo the options (in addition to safe mode, etc) is disable auto-restart after failure.

Just as FYI, the error code was something like 0x00000007 which when googled reveals nothing. I did figure out what the issue was though. My hard drive did not like the fact that I changed everything on it. I reimaged and upgraded to a 64-bit OS. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
wmic recoveros set AutoReboot = False
```