# Can I just replace my motherboard and CPU without further complications?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading motherboard without reloading OS](https://superuser.com/questions/381485/upgrading-motherboard-without-reloading-os)

I've just purchased the i7 2600k and a Gigabyte Z68A-D3H-B3 motherboard.  I want to upgrade my existing setup, a Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3R, Core 2 X6800.

Can I just plug my hard drive and other components to the new setup and boot Windows normally?

What complications could arise?

Comment: You'll likely need to do a repair install of windows

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 7 installed, it could just work.

A few things to keep in mind, though:

1. Backup your data (probably not necessary, but can't hurt)
2. I would advise that you check your BIOS and your hard drive settings
   first (AHCI/RAID/SATA/ENHANCED). Match the hard drive settings to the old PC's BIOS
3. Uninstall all drivers that have an
   installer. Graphics card, mobo, sound card... every driver you can
   uninstall from "Add/Remove Programs" in Windows.
4. Be VERY careful when handling hardware in the exchange process.

Hook up your components and pray.

If it works: install new drivers.
If it does not: make sure you backed up everything before, and install a fresh version of Windows on your new computer. You can also just put the components back in your old PC if that's what you need.

Note: If you had OEM Windows installed on the old PC. Your licence will not work on the new hardware. OEM windows binds to the hardware you activated your licence on. Windows will prompt you for a new key and activation if you had OEM Windows on your old PC.