# Bsod on 2400 Mhz ram

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod

I recently built a new pc.

My pc shuts down randomly and I see a blue screen saying something about "windows has shutdown to prevent damage on itself" the screen only shows for 3 seconds or less, so I cant read it all.

In the bios the only thing I had edited is the ram frequency. I changed it from "auto" to "2400" mhz.

When my ram is on auto it runs on 1333 mhz,and I have no problems.

When my ram is on 2400 it runs on 2400 mhz, and I get the bsod some times, and programs often does not respond.

Heres my specs:

Cpu: AMD FX-9590

Ram: 2*8 Gb (16 Gb) Kingstom HyperX 2400 mhz

Os: Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Motherboard: Asus crosshair v formula-z

Gpu: 2048MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 630

Hdd: 1 Tb seagate (Storing documents, programs and more)

Ssd: 120 Gb Kingston (For the windows files, drivers and programs I use often)

As said when I run the ram on auto is running smooth. I havent got a single crash or a "not responding".

But I would really like to run my ram on 2400 Mhz, or as high as possible.

Thanks

Comment: See the comments in the main question http://superuser.com/questions/378191/disable-auto-restart-after-bsod-from-command-line and it will keep the BSOD on screen. Post the details when you get it. Why not put the RAM back onto Auto!? Why do you need to change the RAM to 2400? You could run MEM TEST but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: My pc is running. I use it right now, but it is running on 1333 mhz ram. Its about how I can make it run on 2400 without getting random bsod and often not responding programs

Comment: Okay, Ill change it to 2400 mhz, but I may take a while before I get the bsod

Comment: Also, what is the BIOS and what revision is it at? Sometimes, the CPU stops this if it's not powerful enough, but yours should be more than powerful enough

Comment: Im pretty sure Im running the lastest version from asus

Comment: OK, let's see what the BSOD reports :)

Comment: Hmm Im running on 2400 now, and I have not got it yet. Any ideas how I can make it appear faster?

Comment: ha ha, I wouldn't worry about forcing it... Just wait until it occurs again. :)

Comment: It just did it. When I started it again I chose "safe mode with command line" And I didnt knew what to write, so I restarted it. Im not sure how I can do it. What is POST? and when shall I press f8

Comment: Boot your PC up again, and as it starts, keep pressing F8

Comment: Just did it. What drive shall I boot from?

Comment: You may need to bump the voltage up a bit on the RAM. Overclocking RAM sometimes may need higher voltage to keep it stable.

Comment: Are you saying you don't need have the option to "disable auto-restart after failure." If not, follow this guide http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/disautorestart.htm

Comment: You really should stop what you're doing. You risk doing damage to your OS installation. Hardware should be confirmed reliable, particularly after frequency and voltage changes, *before* running an OS you care about. Start with memtest86+.

Comment: I finally got an image of the error! http://imgur.com/wEYxpRc